# Formatting a JSON payload for passing to an API POST call in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, format

I have a web aplication where I am able to create extra proprities (keys and values) and pass them in a JSON output. Here is the final format of what is passed from the web application.

```
{
        'abendCode': '',
        'action': 'CREATE',
        'assignGroup': '[Team]',
        'component': '',
        'description': 'test alert',
        'entered': '',
        'logicalName': '',
        'pageGroups': '["[Team]"]',
        'priority': '1',
        'RACF': '',
        'sendPage': 'false',
        'sysProdName': 'MANUAL',
        'transactionId': '',
        'type': 'RESPONDER'
        }
```

I have created a python method to build out a json payload to create a ticket leveraging an api call to POST to our tickeiting system. In the method I do some formatting to strip unnessary characters like ["[Team]"] and replace it with ['Team'] (this is in the pageGroups value). I than remove the square brackets from 'assignGroup': '[Team]' to show 'assignGroup': 'Team'

When I run the code it get a 500, which I am 90% sure it is because my JSON is not properly formatted.

When I run the following in Postman it will create a ticket.

```
{
    "type": "RESPONDER",
    "action": "CREATE",
    "logicalName": "",
    "component": "",
    "entered": "",
    "racfId": "",
    "description": "incident creation",
    "priority": "1",
    "assignGroup": "TEAM",
    "transactionId": "",
    "abendCode": "",
    "sysProdName": "MANUAL",
    "sendPage": "false",
    "pageGroups": ["TEAM"]
}
```

Here is my code with some things changed for removed for sensitivity.

```
import requests
import json
import ast
from datetime import datetime
import re

# Date and time stamp for logging
now = datetime.now()
# Format: month day year day of the week HH:SS:00
# 03/18/2021 Tuesday 07:18:25
dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %A %H:%M:%S ")

ogArray = {
            'abendCode': '',
            'action': 'CREATE',
            'assignGroup': '[Team]',
            'component': '',
            'description': 'test alert',
            'entered': '',
            'logicalName': '',
            'pageGroups': '["[Team]"]',
            'priority': '1',
            'RACF': '',
            'sendPage': 'false',
            'sysProdName': 'MANUAL',
            'transactionId': '',
            'type': 'RESPONDER'
            }

action = "create"
alertId = "ab40f5e4-867c-b80b-a11aeea57731-1617302963378"
Team = "Team"

tcisApiToken = 'api token'
tcisApi_url_base = 'https://api.com/events/v1/'

tcisHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'applicarion/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic {0}'.format(tcisApiToken)}


def createTicket(ogArray, action, alertId, Team):
    api_url_base = Api_url_base
    headers = Headers
    time = dt_string
    api_url = '{0}events'.format(api_url_base)
    print(time + " Alert Id: " + str(alertId))
    data = ogArray
    # do some string processing
    print("---Pre process ogArray" + str(data))
    data['assignGroup'] = (data['assignGroup'][1:-1])
    data = re.sub("\'\[\"\[", '[\'', str(data))
    data = re.sub("\]\"\]\'", '\']', str(data))
    # Having an Issue here, with data[description] with the key ValueError commented it out for now
    # data['description'] = data['description'] + str(" [alertId:" + alertId + "]")
    print("---Print after format" +str(data))

    data = json.dumps(data)
    print("---After dumps" + str(data))

    data = json.loads(data)
    print("---After loads" + str(data))
    print(time + " Action: " + str(action))
    print(time + "JSON payload: " + str(data))
    # Build JSON POST request
    response = requests.post(url=api_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(time + 'API response = ' + str(response.status_code))
    print(time + "Formatted JSON data :" + str(data))
    print(response)
    response_url = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

    if response.status_code == 200 and 'returnCode' in response_url:
        eventId = response_url["eventId"]
        incidentId = response_url["incidentId"]
        print(time + str(response_url))
    elif response.status_code == 200 and 'returnCode' not in response_url:
        print(time + str(response_url))
        print(time + "Failed to create  ticket. It is possible the  team does not exist or payload is formatted incorrectly. Contact  admin for support. See logs for more info.")
    else:
        note = 'Create Ticket Failed.'
        print(time + str(note))
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createTicket = createTicket(ogArray, action, alertId, Team)
```

Here is my output from the original code I am running:

```
    04/02/2021 Friday 16:31:57  Alert Id: ab40f5e4-867c-46e4-b80b-a11aeea57731-1617302963378
---Pre process ogArray{'abendCode': '', 'action': 'CREATE', 'assignGroup': '[APP-SUPPORT]', 'component': '', 'description': 'test alert', 'entered': '', 'logicalName': '', 'pageGroups': '["[APP-SUPPORT]"]', 'priority': '1', 'RACF': '', 'sendPage': 'false', 'sysProdName': 'MANUAL', 'transactionId': '', 'type': 'RESPONDER'}
---Print after format{'abendCode': '', 'action': 'CREATE', 'assignGroup': 'APP-SUPPORT', 'component': '', 'description': 'test alert', 'entered': '', 'logicalName': '', 'pageGroups': ['APP-SUPPORT'], 'priority': '1', 'RACF': '', 'sendPage': 'false', 'sysProdName': 'MANUAL', 'transactionId': '', 'type': 'RESPONDER'}
---After dumps"{'abendCode': '', 'action': 'CREATE', 'assignGroup': 'APP-SUPPORT', 'component': '', 'description': 'test alert', 'entered': '', 'logicalName': '', 'pageGroups': ['APP-SUPPORT'], 'priority': '1', 'RACF': '', 'sendPage': 'false', 'sysProdName': 'MANUAL', 'transactionId': '', 'type': 'RESPONDER'}"
---After loads{'abendCode': '', 'action': 'CREATE', 'assignGroup': 'APP-SUPPORT', 'component': '', 'description': 'test alert', 'entered': '', 'logicalName': '', 'pageGroups': ['APP-SUPPORT'], 'priority': '1', 'RACF': '', 'sendPage': 'false', 'sysProdName': 'MANUAL', 'transactionId': '', 'type': 'RESPONDER'}
04/02/2021 Friday 16:31:57  Action: create
04/02/2021 Friday 16:31:57 JSON payload: {'abendCode': '', 'action': 'CREATE', 'assignGroup': 'APP-SUPPORT', 'component': '', 'description': 'test alert', 'entered': '', 'logicalName': '', 'pageGroups': ['APP-SUPPORT'], 'priority': '1', 'RACF': '', 'sendPage': 'false', 'sysProdName': 'MANUAL', 'transactionId': '', 'type': 'RESPONDER'}
04/02/2021 Friday 16:31:57 API response = 500
04/02/2021 Friday 16:31:57 Formatted JSON data :{'abendCode': '', 'action': 'CREATE', 'assignGroup': 'TCIS-APP-SUPPORT', 'component': '', 'description': 'test alert', 'entered': '', 'logicalName': '', 'pageGroups': ['APP-SUPPORT'], 'priority': '1', 'RACF': '', 'sendPage': 'false', 'sysProdName': 'MANUAL', 'transactionId': '', 'type': 'RESPONDER'}
<Response [500]>


createTicket = createTicket(ogArray, action, alertId, Team)
  File "D:\AtomProjects\pingtest\manualTicketCreate.py", line 70, in createTicket
    response_url = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
  File "D:\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[Finished in 0.931s]
```

I am not sure if there needs to be a dumps, since I am formatting the JSON strings before the dumps. I have been all over the net to solve this but I am stumped at this point. I have also looked at the error outputs and I do not understand them, even when searching for them on the web. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going wrong -

1. You are calling json.loads right after json.dumps . This now deserializes your payload back into a regular python dictionary.
2. You want to send serialized JSON object as your payload.

Here are your options:
OPTION 1:

```
data = json.dumps(data)
print("---After dumps" + str(data))
response = requests.post(url=api_url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

OPTION 2:
requests.post supports a json parameter, where you can use your python dict directly and it will serialize it internally.

```
# Note that json.dumps is commented out in this option.
# data = json.dumps(data)
response = requests.post(url=api_url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the insight on the JSON.dumps. I also had to add a line of code to evaluate the data before dumping to get the proper formatting for JSON

`data = ast.literal_eval(data)
 data = json.dumps(data)`